# Why does Wolfram Alpha say that $\sqrt{1}=-1$?

Tags: arithmetic, wolfram-alpha, roots-of-unity

Why does [Wolfram Alpha say that $\sqrt{1}=-1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%281%29)?

[image]

Is this a mistake or what? Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not? The square root has two values (except for the radicand $0$). But for me, it returns $1$, boringly, as the principal root.

Comment: It doesn't even say $\sqrt {1}=-1$. Where are you getting this?

Comment: put by plot $\sqrt{x}=y$ the plot give me positive y

Comment: $\sqrt{1}$ can be interpreted as the zero set of the polynomial $x^2-1$. Depending on the ring, this can have all sorts of solutions. But simply $\{\pm 1\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, like in any field.

Comment: **Related / possible duplicates:** [Square roots — positive and negative](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative), [Why is the even root of a number always positive?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41878/why-is-the-even-root-of-a-number-always-positive), [Why is $\sqrt{4} = 2$ and Not $\pm 2$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380359/why-is-sqrt4-2-and-not-pm-2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you read the results carefully? It **does** give $1$ as the answer:

[image]

It then helpfully mentions that $-1$ is also a 2nd root of $1$:

[image]

which is perfectly correct, because $(-1)^2=1$.

Comment: but why ? 
mistake or what ?

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh: Do you understand that $(-1)\times(-1)=1$?

Comment: if $\sqrt{1}=-1$ and $\sqrt{1}=1$ so 1=-1

Comment: sure (−1)×(−1)=1

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh You are giving the same meaning to two different terms. **The square root of a positive number** $x$ is the only positive $a$ such that $a^2=x$. While **a square root** of a positive number $x$ is any number $a$ such that $a^2=x$. The indefinite and definite articles **a** and **the** make all the difference.

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh: Note that *no one* - not Wolfram Alpha, not me, not anyone else - is saying that $\sqrt{1}=-1$, so I don't know where you're getting that from. And clearly your statement that $1=-1$ is false. I recommend reading [the Wikipedia article on the square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root)

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh, you seem to think there is only one square root of $1$. Maybe you are wrong?

Comment: yes I say that there is only one square root of 1

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh: How do you reconcile that with the fact $(-1)^2=1$? A square root of a number $x$ is a number $y$ such that $y^2 = x$.

Answer (score 3):

There are ***two*** real values which are *roots* of $1$: $$(-1)^2 = (1)^2 = 1$$

Exactly **one** of those values, the non-negative root, is called the **[principal square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436982/why-sqrt1-1-by-wolfram/436988#436988)** of $1$, and is the real value returned by the the ***square root function*** $f$: $$f: \mathbb R^{\geq 0} \to \mathbb R^{\geq 0},\quad f(x) = \sqrt x,\quad\text{where}\;f(1) = \sqrt 1 = 1$$

**but** $(-1)$ is also, by definition, a *real* (non-principal) root of $1$.

See also [principal square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root) in Wikipedia.

Comment: $+1{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

$-1$ is a perfectly valid square root of 1... think about it: $(-1)^2=1$, after all!

It is not what we usually call the "principle branch" of the square root, where you would expect to get 1.

Answer (score 1):

By writing $\sqrt{x}$ with $x>0$ , you implicitly mean the [principal square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root) which is always positive. This is called *the* square root of $x$.

There is always another (negative) number whose square is $x$, namely $-\sqrt{x}$, in your case $-1$. The wolfram alpha has made it clear by saying:

```
1 (real, principle root)
-1 (real root)
```