# Why doesn't Square root function give range as Real?

Tags: functions

When we write $x^2=4$.   It means $x=+2$ or $x=-2$.

So then why is the range of the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+4} \quad$ $[2,\infty)$ and not $(-\infty, - 2] \cup [2,\infty)$?

Please give me a hint, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Notice that you write "function".  You have to take either the negative value or the positive value consistently to make this so. And the standard is to take the positive value.

Comment: Find the inverse function. Its domain is the range of your current function.

Comment: Okay, I get it now, thank you everyone!

Comment: This has been asked frequently: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/26363

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ means the *non-negative* square root of $x.$ It is defined this way so that $f:x\to \sqrt{x}$ is a *function*. $f:x\to\pm \sqrt{x}$ is not a function. So it doesn't really make sense to write $f:x\to\pm \sqrt{x}.$

Comment: See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380359/why-is-sqrt4-2-and-not-pm-2