# Why do we assume principal root for the notation $\sqrt{}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, radicals

I'm wondering why when $n$ is even we always assume the positive root for $\sqrt[n]{}.$ For example, if we have $x = \sqrt{4}$, we always assume $x = 2$. Yet when we have $x^2 = 4,$ we write $x = \pm\sqrt{4} \Longrightarrow x = -2, 2$.

The problem is that if I take the 1st equation, and square both sides, I get
$$x = \sqrt{4} \Longrightarrow x^2 = 4 \Longrightarrow x = \pm\sqrt{4} \Longrightarrow x = -2, 2$$ My teacher says that if you introduce the radical sign, use $\pm$, but those two equations are the same under the rules about radicals she taught us, so the "taking the positive root" rule feels arbitrary to me. I get that people want to make the radical mean something without ambiguity, but making arbitrary rules, like taking just the positive answer, seems to confuse things and lead to inconsistency, like in the above.

There are other examples, such as solving for $x$, then substituting the original equation with the value of $x$, and not getting it to work because you can only take the positive root.

For things like the Pythagorean theorem, people like to say it's obvious to take the positive one only, but there are ways to represent the Pythagorean theorem without relying on human judgement to decipher the final answer.  Say you have a right triangle with legs $a=3$, $b=4$, and you want to find c.  So you do: $3^2 + 4^2 = c^2$, $c > 0$. and solve the systems of equations, just like any other: $c = \pm\sqrt{25} \Longrightarrow c = -5, 5$.  $c = -5, 5$ intersects $c > 0$ at $c = 5$, so the answer is $c = 5$.  I don't see why you would need to redefine square root: $\pm\sqrt{}$ to mean [principal square root](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalSquareRoot.html): $\sqrt{}$ to find the correct answer.

Does the "taking the positive root" rule have something to do with imaginary numbers, or am I missing something? (I am not asking if $\sqrt{}$ means positive, I'm asking why.)

Comment: One way to dodge this seemingly magical "take the $\pm$ when you take square roots on both sides of an equation" is to instead introduce the $\pm$ when you solve an *absolute value* equation, by introducing an additional step. In this situation you're doing $x^2=4$ hence $|x|=2$ hence $x=\pm 2$. In that first step we took the principal root; we only introduced the other one through the absolute value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Square roots -- positive and negative](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative)

Comment: I don't see how you can classify $-2, 2$ as a single number under the absolute value sign, even though both absolute values would be 2.

Comment: Not a duplicate, his what asking what, mine is asking why.

Comment: Well I guess x is a number. What you said makes sense but I still don't get why it's assumed you take the positive root.

Comment: @codersarecool The point is that for any $y>0$ there exist two solutions to $|x|=y$. We can manage this fact while still having $\sqrt{x}$ be a (single-valued) function by introducing this additional step. This way of working with things also works better with inequalities.

Comment: Yes y has to be greater than 0 since its an absolute value, but why do you want $\pm\sqrt{}$ to be a function? and how does it work better with inequalities?

Comment: You don't want $\pm \sqrt{x}$ to be a function, you want $\sqrt{x}$ to be a function, basically because it's convenient for things to be functions. It works better with inequalities because $\sqrt{x}$ is a strictly increasing function on the nonnegative real numbers, so that for example $x^2 \leq 4$ is exactly equivalent to $|x| \leq 2$. It is *not* equivalent to $x \leq 2$, and it is certainly not equivalent to "$x \leq \pm 2$" whatever that even means.

Comment: Nine times out of ten, if we're solving a problem, the principal root is the only one we want. Plus, functions are more useful than relations. So, we made the square root a function.

Comment: That still doesn't answer why you can turn $x = \sqrt{4} \Longrightarrow x^2 = 4 \Longrightarrow x = \pm\sqrt{4} \Longrightarrow x = -2, 2$

Comment: Because that comma there means "or". $x$ was actually equal to $2$, and you did some manipulations and concluded that it must be equal to either $2$ or $-2$, which is technically true, but you've forgotten that it was $2$ in the first place (so that none of these manipulations were actually necessary).

Comment: So by squaring both sides you're actually losing information, which means that what you thought the answer was before was only a possibility, else I should be able to take the square root again and get one answer.  You can't just say somethings a function and expect the rules of true radicals still apply.

Comment: By the laws of mathematics, $x = \sqrt{4}$ and $x^2 = 4$ are the same, but you don't know the answer if you're presented with one, and do know the answer if you're presented with another.

Comment: $x=\sqrt{4}$ implies that $x=2$ and only $2$, again because we use the square root symbol to denote only the principle root.  $x^2=4$ implies that $|x|=2$ but does not directly imply that $x=2$, it could have been something else (*namely $-2$*) so no the two are not the same.  Do not confuse the logical if-then ($\implies$) with the logical if-and-only-if ($\iff$)

Comment: Indeed $x=\sqrt{4}\implies x^2=4$ but $x^2=4~~\not\!\!\!\implies x=\sqrt{4}$

Comment: No, $x=\sqrt{4}$ and $x^2=4$ are not the same. $x^2=4$ is equivalent to $|x|=\sqrt{4}$. Squaring both sides did destroy information but that does not somehow mean that we have to "apply a multivalued function on both sides" to find the solution. It suffices to understand that the "inverse" of $|x|$ (which has no standard name) is multivalued, which has nothing to do with radicals intrinsically.

Comment: Yes it does mean that you need to apply a multi valued function on both sides because all you know now (since it is still the same equation according to the laws of mathematics so I can manipulate it and should get the same answer) is that x times x is 4.

Comment: No, really, there is no "law of mathematics" that says that the equations $x=\sqrt{4}$ and $x^2=4$ are equivalent equations (i.e. that they characterize the same solution set). The rules only tell you that the solution set of the former is contained in the solution set of the latter. You won't be able to grasp this concept until you get that idea out of your mind.

Comment: I guess what I don't get is how squaring both sides destroys information, even when not using the square root function.

Comment: It probably has something to do with negative numbers being fundamentally different than positives.  It would work if we only used positive numbers.

Comment: Related $\longrightarrow$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343894/if-pm-x2-x-then-sqrtx-x?rq=1

Comment: For what it's worth, I know several mathematicians who regurlarly use the notation $\sqrt x$ to denote the set of all square roots of $x$, rather than just the positive one. Depending on the context they're working on, it's more practical to use one notation or the other. In most contexts, we try to be as specific as we can, and having $\sqrt x$ refer to all square roots rather than a particular one would cause more ambiguity and awkward language. So we pick the positive one. Contrast with complex numbers: they also have two square roots, but there is no obvious way to pick one, so we don't.

Comment: Also compare with $\arccos$ and all those inverse trigonometry functions. The function $\cos$ doesn't have an inverse, but we still want to be able to express solutions of the equation $\cos(x) = y$, so we define an arbitrary "principal inverse" of $\cos$, and use it to express other inverses.

Comment: Finally, compare with the notation $a \mod b$. In most contexts mathematician find it more convenient to talk about equivalency classes than about a particular representative of the class, therefore $a \mod b$ is **not** the remainder of $a$ divided by $b$, nor any "principal solution" of $b \,|\, (a - x)$.

Comment: We "destroy information" whenever we use a function that maps two different values onto the same value. The function $f(x)=x^2$ maps $x$ and $-x$ onto the same result. Therefore if all you have is the result, you can't tell which possible input it came from. Certainly $x=2 \implies x^2=4,$ right? But if you only know that $x^2=4$ you don't know that $x=2.$

Answer (score 14):

Here is a short answer to the question in the title of OP:

> Well, if we don't do so, what could a better alternative be?

### What is the notation $\sqrt{}$?

The confusion seems to be from understanding of the notation $\sqrt{}$. When writing, for instance $\sqrt{16}$, one pronounces it as "square root of $16$". However, what one really means is "the principal square root of $16$".

Let's go back to the definitions. A *square root* of a real number $a$ is a number $y$ such that $y^2 = a$; in other words, a number $y$ whose square is $a$. For example, $4$ and $−4$ are *square roots* of $16$ because $4^2=(-4)^2=16$. Note carefully that the notation $\sqrt{}$ is not involved in this definition at all.

Now, for every given positive real number, say $16$ again, there are two "square roots" (note carefully again that we don't write $\sqrt{x}$ for "square roots of $x$" yet) of it. What if one wants specifically to refer to the positive one? Instead of explicitly saying "I'm refering to the positive square root of $16$", one uses the notation $\sqrt{}$ to define $\sqrt{16}$ as the positive square root of $16$. Here comes the notation $\sqrt{}$. Of course you are losing "information" when you write $\sqrt{16}$ to mean "the positive square root of $16$". Because it is by definition so. What does one do for the "lost information"? One naturally has $-\sqrt{16}$ as the negative square root of $16$.

One can put two definitions together to see what is really going on:

- A "square root" of a real number $a$ is a number $y$ such that $y^2=a$;
- Given a positive real number $x$, the notation $\sqrt{x}$ is *defined* as a positive real number $y$ such that  $y^2=x$. And in this case, we write $y=\sqrt{x}$.

### *Why* is $\sqrt{}$ defined in the way above?

**If one does not *define*** $\sqrt{a}$ as the positive square root of $a$ **and instead** as the "square root**s** of $a$", then one would have $\sqrt{16}=\pm 4$. Now how would you write the answer to the following question?

> What is the positive real number $x$ such that $x^2=\pi$?

---

[Added: ]Compare the following two possible **definitions** for the notation $\sqrt{}$:

- I. For any positive real number $a$, define $\sqrt{a}$ as the square roots of $a$;
- II. For any positive real number $a$, define $\sqrt{a}$ as the *positive* square root of $a$;

Now, if one uses definition I, then $\sqrt{16}=\pm4$. **With this definition**, you have perfectly what you might want:
$$
x^2=16\Rightarrow x=\pm 4;\quad\text{and }x=\sqrt{16}=\pm4.
$$

If one uses definition II instead, on the other hand, one would have $\sqrt{16}=4$.

You might be happier with definition I and ask *why* on earth one prefers II. Here is "why". Suppose you are asked to solve the following problem.

> Find the solution to the equation $x^2-\pi=0$ *such that* $x>0$.

If one uses definition II, then one immediately has $x=\sqrt{\pi}$.

Now if one uses definition I, $x=\sqrt{\pi}$ would be the WRONG answer.

---

One more lesson from Terry Tao:

> It’s worth bearing in mind that notation is ultimately an artificial human invention, rather than an innate feature of the mathematics one is working on; sometimes, two writers happen to use the same symbol to denote two rather different concepts, but this does not necessarily mean that these concepts have any deeper connection to them.

Comment: $\sqrt{\pi}$.  I understand the notation, I'm wondering why, not what.  Take for example, the first example I provided.  As a programmer, I have a good understanding of what a function is.  I see the square root function as an unbalanced chemical equation.  Even though "9/10 times", you want the positive root, mathematics doesn't care, and you will get conundrums like my first example.  I get that it's easier to say $\pm\sqrt{x}$ than $-\sqrt{x}$ (like you said, when we would like to refer to the negative). I don't get why we treat the square root function like the mathematical $\pm\sqrt{}$.

Comment: By unbalanced chemical equation, I mean that you can deduce a balanced one, but if you try to use the unbalanced one, you will get incorrect results.

Comment: @codersarecool, that mathematics doesn't care is irrelevant: mathematicians do. Our notations are purely based on convenience, and the accepted practice is the most convenient one.

Comment: Accept when it doesn't actually work.  Mathematics exists regardless of what mathematicians define as standards.

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that when you squared you got an equation that seems to be equivalent to the original, but in reality it is not. The original implicitly has the restriction that the $x$ must be a non-negative number, but the second does not.

As the one you are solving is the first and not the second, the restriction must remain present, and if it cannot be implicitly, you must write it explicitly:

$$
x^2 = 4,    x\geq0
$$

And so nothing has changed. When we solve an equation we must identify firstly what the restrictions are and keep them present, because sometimes algebraic manipulations change the set of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking at a specific equation, like $x^3 = 8$, you need to look at the bigger problem $x^3 = y$. What you want is, given $y$, to find what $x$ is. In other words, you want a function $f$ such that $x = f(y)$. In this example, $x = \sqrt[3] y$ and you problem is solved. This point of view works great when the exponent is an odd number.

Now consider the equation $x^2 = y$. We have a problem because, for example, $3^2 = 9$ and $(-3)^2 = 9$. A **function** $x = f(y)$ can only return **one value** for each $y$.  So either $3 = f(9)$ or $-3 = f(9)$ but we can't have both if we want $f$ to be a function. So, if we want $f(y) =\sqrt y$ to be a **function**, then we have to choose. The choice was $f(y) = \sqrt y$ is the positive square root of $y$.

So, when you see an equation like $x^2 = 25$. Then $x = \sqrt{25}$ gives you **a solution** $x=5$. If you want both solutions, then you have to write $x = \pm \sqrt{25}$.

Comment: $x^2=25$ gives you $x = 5$ or $x = -5$.  $x = \sqrt{25}$ gives you $x = 5$.  The only way you could plot something like $y^2 = x$ is to make a graph of y and graph $f(y)=y^2$.  It's not impossible to represent in a visual way even.

Comment: @codersarecool -  It's not hard to plot $y^2 = x$. But it is not the graph of a function. The function $ y=\sqrt x$ is a **branch** of $y^2 = x$ that provides **a** solution. To get both solutions you need to use the other branch function $y = -\sqrt x$.

Comment: I guess another question I'd have is why do functions need to have only one solution.  I'd assume it's by definition.  So then I'd ask what purpose does having one solution have.  Simplicity?  Passing the vertical line test?  Those all seem like arbitrary goals.  You lose sign info when squaring, and the square root should be able to deal with that.  What's the problem with having an x correspond to 2 y values?

Comment: Functions do not have one solution. They have one value for each input. The value nowadays is that that value can be computed on a calculator. From that value, the other solutions can, in may cases,  be calculated easily.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematicians use the principal square root more often.

We would rather use $ \pm \sqrt x $ in a few cases then have to write $ |\sqrt x|$ all the time.

That's pretty much the only reason why.

---

$ \sqrt \cdot $ is usually how we notate a **principal square root**. It is **not** an inverse operation.

$ \pm \sqrt \cdot $ is usually how we notate a (true) **square root**. Is is the inverse operation of $ \cdot^2 $.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it shouldn't be presented as a "rule". The reason we don't apply the plus and minus when solving even radical equations is because the domain for these functions is intentionally restricted. It must be restricted to values of x for which the radicand is positive. In the "Real Number System" we cannot take even roots of negative numbers. This would require complex numbers. Therefore we take only the "Principal Root" because under the restricted domain, there is no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the context in which the square-root is being used.

$\pm$ is used when finding solutions to a condition to accurately describe the domain in which the condition is true. For instance, take $x^2 + 5 = 14$. Isolate $x^2$: $x^2 = 9$. This condition is satisfied such that $x = \pm 3$; thus, to encompass the full domain in which the condition is true, we use the $\pm$ operator.

$\pm$ is not used for algebraically manipulated functions that happen to involve radicals, such as $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. Functions are defined as input-output systems such that each input has one output (i.e. only one branch). $f(x) = \pm \sqrt{x}$ contradicts this definition because it outputs two quantities for one input. Now, that doesn't necessarily mean that you cannot declare $f(x)$ to be $\pm \sqrt{x}$, but $f(x)$ will not be an I/O function and will lose certain properties that comes with the consequence of having more than one branch when dealing with applied mathematics. Multi-valued I/O systems are almost exclusively used for solving a condition (e.g. the Lambert W Function $W(x)$).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering why when $n$ is even we always assume the positive root for $\sqrt[n]{}.$

$\sqrt4=2$ is true by definition and agreement—not by provisional assumption.

> The problem is that  I get
> $$x = 2 \color{red}\implies x^2 = 4 \color{red}\implies x = \pm\sqrt{4} \color{red}\implies x = \pm2\tag1$$
> I get that people want to make the radical mean something without ambiguity, but making arbitrary rules, like taking just the positive answer, seems to confuse things and lead to inconsistency, like in the above.

Statement $(1)$ is **not** a problem nor an inconsistency: it can be summarised as $$\text{if $x$ equals $2,\,$ then $x$ equals either $-2$ or $2$},$$ which is perfectly correct. Analogously, $$\text{if today is Monday, then today is a weekday}.$$

To be clear: statement $(1)$ claims **neither** that $$x = \pm2\implies x = 2\\\text{(if today is a weekday, then today is Monday)}$$ **nor** that $$x = \pm2 \iff x = 2\\\text{(weekdays and Mondays are synonyms)}.$$

More generally, letting $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ be equations, the statement $$A(x)\color{red}{\implies}B(x)$$ means that every solution of $A(x)$ is a solution of $B(x),$ while the statement $$A(x)\color{red}{\iff}B(x)$$ means that $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ have the same solutions.

[image]