# What does it mean to be equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definition, radicals

Essentially, what I'm asking is what it means for two numbers to be equivalent.

**Why I'm asking this:**

- If $a=b$ and $b=c$, then $a=c$. But if $a=5$, $b=\sqrt{25}$ and $c=-5$, obviously $a$ is inequal to $c$.
- Also, is it correct to say that the square root of $25$ is equal to the fourth root of $625$?

**Thanks!**

Comment: You have to specify which square root, the positive or negative one. Otherwise $b$ is not well-defined.

Comment: @Mathematician42 It's unspecified

Comment: If it is unspecified, then there's your problem: unspecified square roots are not well-defined, leading immediately to violations of the laws of equality.

Comment: That's the problem! (Don't get the downvote, this is a valid question)

Comment: @Mathematician42 But how is equality defined?

Comment: That's a rather deep question. First of all, here we are talking about an equality of numbers. So the first question is how numbers are defined! A mathematically correct definition would take us off topic.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Yeah, that's what I meant :) :)

Comment: The issue here is that you are actually using two different $b$'s since specifying $b$ as a square root of 5 is not uniquely defined. Both $b=5$ and $b'=-5$ are square roots of 25. You are not talking about only one number in that way. (Also, usually people mean **positive** square root when they say square root to avoid issues like this, indeed that's well-defined).

Comment: Indeed, the definition of equality is a very deep question, and the answer is different depending on whom you talk to. In first-order logic, the notion of equality is purely syntactic: we say that two things $a$ and $b$ are equal if we can perform certain manipulations of symbols and validly obtain the string $a=b$. In constructive type theory, the equality of two objects is a *type*, and to prove that two things are equal is to exhibit a member of that type. But here, your problem is confusion over the definition of the function $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$, as others have pointed out.

Comment: Anyway, be careful with square roots, otherwise you get this:

\begin{eqnarray}
1 &=& \sqrt{1}\\
&=& \sqrt{(-1)^2}\\
&=& \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}\\
&=& i\cdot i\\
&=& i^2\\
&=& -1
\end{eqnarray}

Different issue though.

Comment: @Mathematician42 I disagree strongly with "You have to specify which square root, the positive or negative one". By overwhelming convention, an unqualified $\sqrt{\cdot}$ indicates the positive one by default.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: No, a square root of a number $a$ is a number $y$ such that $y^2=a$. The positive square root is called the principle square root of $a$. Wikipedia agrees with this as well. I agree that the symbol $\sqrt{a}$ indicates the principal square root of $a$ but that is not what a said. In fact, this is exactly what you did in your answer, you specified $\sqrt{\cdot}$ but not the definition of square root.

Comment: @Mathematician42 I agree with everything you have said in that comment up until "that is not what a said", and indeed my answer below basically says the same thing. But $\sqrt{\cdot}$ never, ever indicates the negative square root, so it's simply wrong to assert that $\sqrt{25} = -5$. One may sometimes abuse notation to say that $\sqrt{25} = \pm 5$, but this is a bad abuse and it always requires clarification.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: Aah, the question was edited, it said "square root of 25" first! Whew, got confused there :)

Comment: @Mathematician42 It still does....

Comment: Nono, now it says $\sqrt{25}=b$ as well, it didn't before (see the edit history). The edit of TPace changed the issue.

Comment: @Mathematician42 My mistake, you're right :)

Comment: Similar confusion: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2001412/9464

Comment: @Jack Looks useful :)

Comment: To be short: given a positive real number $x$, "*a* square root of $x$", "*the* square root of $x$" and the notation "$\sqrt{x}$" could be three different things.

Comment: Let us write $\def\C{\operatorname{color}}\C(x)$ to mean the color of thing $x$.  For example, $\C(\text{strawberry})$ is red.  We have $\C(\text{strawberry}) = \C(\text{cherry})$ because they are both red. But that does not mean that strawberries are cherries.  When you say $\sqrt{25} = \pm 5$, all it means is that $+5$ and $-5$ have the same square. That does not make them the same thing. And you could, I suppose, write $\sqrt[\text{color}]{\text{red}} = \{\text{strawberry}, \text{cherry}\}$, but that still doesn't mean that strawberries are cherries; it just means they are the same color.

Answer (score 2):

We say that $y$ **is a square root of $x$** if $y^2 = x$.

We define a function $\sqrt{\cdot} : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ ("the square root function") by $$\sqrt{x} := \text{the nonnegative number $y$ such that $y^2 = x$}$$

So you can see that $\sqrt{x}$ is a square root of $x$.

Not every square root of $4$ is equal to $\sqrt{4} = 2$. It turns out to be the case that $-\sqrt{4} = -2$ is also a square root of $4$.

When we refer to *the* square root of $x$, we mean $\sqrt{x}$; that is, the unique nonnegative number which squares to give $x$. When we refer to *a* square root of $x$, we mean any of the numbers which square to give $x$. It is a fact that there are usually two of these, and that one is the negative of the other; so in practice, we may refer to $\pm \sqrt{x}$ if we wish to identify all the square roots of a number. Only the positive one - that is, $\sqrt{x}$ - is the "principal" square root (or "the square root", or if it's really confusing from context, "the positive square root"); but both are square roots.

Comment: +1, but is equality defined then assuming that the roots are positive??

Comment: @AdiC That's like saying "is the equality $5 \times \frac{1}{5} = 1$ defined assuming that $\frac{1}{5}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $5$?". The answer is "yes, but it's not really assuming anything; it's just the definition".

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

By [definition, in the real numbers,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Properties_and_uses)  $\sqrt{25}=+5$  (the **positive** number such that its square is $25$).

And the same for any root of even index.

Note that if we define:

$b=\{$a real number such that $b^2=25\}$  than $b$ can have the two different values $b=\pm5$ and we cannot write an identity as $a=b$ or $c=b$.

Comment: What about the -5 possiblity??

Comment: @Adi that's not written as $\sqrt{25}$

Comment: As a consequence of the definition we write: $-5=-\sqrt{25}$. In general: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Comment: I added something to my answer that  can be useful ( I hope....)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an operator that yields more than one solution, then obviously the solutions are going to be different (otherwise there would only be one). But this does *not* mean they are equal.

Your example involves the function $f(x)=\sqrt x$, with $f(25)=\pm5$. Although both $-5$ and $5$ satisfy $\sqrt{25}$, $-5$ is clearly not the same as $5$. In other words, saying that the negative square root is equal to that of the positive makes no sense.

As suggested in a comment, to avoid this confusion, we use the *principal square root*: $f(x)=|\sqrt x|$

This may be extended to equations outputting two or more solutions. An example of this is solving the cubic $$x^3-2x^2-x+2=(x+1)(x-1)(x-2)=0$$ Here, $-1$, $1$ and $2$ are solutions, but $-1\neq1\neq2$.